# Oracle - storing user settings

Tags: oracle, settings

User has signed up for multiple teams (less than 30).

UserTeam table - UserId, TeamId

How about I store this as varchar like "123:0;124:1;155:1" where 123, 124 and 155 are team-ids, is there any better method? or maybe just "124:155" which means just store the teamids that do have the permission.

UserScore - UserId, ActivityId, ScoreId, TeamId's?

What do you suggest for Oracle database?

Edit: Total number of teams could be tens of thousands or something, but total number of teams allotted to the user will be less than 30.

Comment: I'd use a many-to-many relationship table.

Comment: @GuiGi Could you please explain?

Comment: It's what Robert Merkwürdigeliebe answered: Place the relationship in a separate table, with foreign key constraints to your entity tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use normalization rules to design your data model. From there de-normalize is necessary from a performance point of view.

```
**User**
UserId
UserData

**Team**
TeamId
TeamData


**UserTeam**
UserId
TeamId

foreign key constraints to user and team table

**UseScore** 
UserId
TeamId
ActivityId
Score

foreign key constraints to user, team and activity table
```

Comment: so ActivityId and Score will be repeated - meaning possibly 30 rows for each score?

Comment: That is totally depended on the information you need to store, functional specifications. Do you need to save the score for every activity of a user?

Comment: I think you functional specifications are not totally clear. But storing data as a csv string in a varchar2 field is not the way to go IMHO.

Comment: Scored are definitely needed for these "activities" or "tasks" - they do not occur everyday necessarily... like once a week on average.